# Problem with axios + React and Redux fornodejs/express + passport + jwt api

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, passport.js, react-fullstack

I have created the api with route api/login, I have client in server folder so it can be the url without http (I have proxy for that). 
The problem is when I submit the request. I have 500 error in browser(from catch(error) ).
Here is my action creater:

```
export const loginUser = (email,password) => {
  return function(dispatch) {
    // const token = 'my secret token', I dont know where to put it
   axios.post(
       'api/login', {email: email, password: password}
   ).then((response) => dispatch({type: LOGIN_USER, payload:response}))
  .catch((error) => {
  console.log("axios error:",error);
  });
 }
}
```

In submit function in React I have email and password as a state, so I pass it into action.
I am not sure what I have to put in axios, I suppose I need to add by secret token from jwt?

I really appreciate any advises. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what's the error detail ?

Comment: maybe this problem is because you have a proxy. Check [this solution](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1679#issuecomment-407406296)

Answer (score 0):

in the normal application when you’ve logged in successfully then gives you access token...
500 error means probably you have problem to backand(in my opinion).

i show you my examples 
login helper function

```
function signin(email, password) {
    const user = axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'url',
        data: {
            email,
            password,
        },
        responseType: 'json',
    });
    return user;
}
```

this is action creator

```
export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
    dispatch(request());
    try {
        const res = await api.signin(email, password);
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
        return dispatch(success(res.data.user));
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(failure(error.response.data.message));
    }
};
```

and also i have  one more function which have auth header.
each request to back checks expired or not my token 
let see

```
function getProfile(token) {
    const user = axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'url',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        responseType: 'json',
    });

    return user;
}
```

and in front i have error handler function which checks if returns 401 error redirecting to login  page